# Laundering clothes before the 9 days

Tags: halacha, clothing, nine-days, washing-clothes

I know that one should not wash his clothes during the 9 days, and that one should also not wear "freshly laundered clothes" during this time except on Shabbos.  My question is, what constitutes "freshly laundered clothes"? Is it permissible to do laundry immediately before the 9 days and then wear those clothes during the 9 days?  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17765/759

Comment: It is permissible to do laundry immediately before the 9 days, and then to wipe the clothes on the floor to slightly soil them (or put them on and wear them a bit).  Wiping laundered clothes on the floor is the minhag in our community.  Note that this must be done before Rosh Chodesh Av (i.e before sundown today).

Comment: @SamGoldberg An interesting custom. Can you source it? I can't seem to understand why the soiling would need to be done before Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I checked with our Rav about this (who is where I heard this from originally).  The source of wiping on the floor is from "contemporary" halakhah book, but he didn't remember who he read it from.  Regarding doing before Rosh Chodesh Av, it seems logical that if you are soiling the clothing, it shouldn't matter if it's done during the 9 days, but he wasn't sure about whether it mattered or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are asking if "freshly laundered" means not worn since the last time they were laundered or if it means that they just came out of the laundry recently (time-wise). Obviously, the phrase "freshly laundered" doesn't show up in the Shulchan Aruch, but looking at what he does say (OC 551:3):

> וכן המכובסים מקודם, בין ללבוש בין להציע בהם המטה‏
>   And similarly [included in the prohibition is] that which was laundered before [the Nine Days], whether to wear it or to spread it on a bed [ie a sheet].

He doesn't mention any time factor, but just seems to include anything that had previously been laundered (and presumably not worn). This is the common practice among everyone I know.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Orach Chaim 551:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=47) freshly laundered clothing and linen such as towels, sheets and tablecloths, may not be worn or used during the Nine Days.

Comment: Also I think you mean napkins and not tablecloths. Most people nowadays don't wipe their hands on the tablecloth.

Comment: Wasn't the question "what constitutes 'freshly laundered clothes'"? If so, how does this answer? All you say is that freshly laundered clothes are forbidden. He already knew that.