# Wearing clean but not "freshly laundered" clothes in the 9 Days

Tags: clothing, nine-days, cleaning

As an extension of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/laundering-clothes-before-the-9-days/17822) unanswered question, and based on the site linked to in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17765/freshly-laundered-clothes-in-the-nine-days) question, what does "freshly laundered" mean?

I had a bunch of long sleeved shirts laundered in mid-June but then my summer wardrobe kicked in and I didn't wear any of those shirts. If I wanted to wear one of the shirts now, it would still be "freshly" cleaned in the sense that it hasn't been worn since it was washed, but not "freshly" cleaned in the sense that it was done recently. What if the shirts hadn't been worn after being laundered in March or even September? Is there a time limit to the idea of "freshly laundered" or is it strictly a function of "not having been worn"?

Since there is at least one other way of making clothes "not freshly washed" without wearing them (by laying them on the floor, even without trampling on them - Shulchan Aruch w/Mishnah Berurah 551:3, Piskei Tshuvos 551:17), could 'time elapsed' constitute a valid way to make clothes wearable?

Comment: I think generally if it doesn't feel fresh, it's okay.

Comment: from what I have heard in the past even wearing a piece of clothing once for even just the amount of time it takes to put on and take off would make the clothing no longer freshly laundered. Which is why people who need to do clothing before the 9 days after it comes out will put the clothing on and then immediately take it off.

Comment: 2nd @Dude. It would seem, also, that it is enough that the clothing be dropped on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Yalkut Yosef English Ta'aniyot 206.116 (see note there also) defines no longer freshly laundered as wearing for an hour. Some other opinions define even less time such as Or'Letziyon as long enough to absorb sweat. Hazon Ovadya pg 232 cites an opinion of even 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Such clothing is called fresh because you did not wear it before the 9 days and there is no such thing as *time elapsed*.

Comment: Hi opoil. How do you know this? Please [edit] in a source. Since we don't know you, there's no reason we should just take your word for this.

Comment: it says so in bear tovia [dayan in viznits

Comment: You should add the correct citation into your answer and give the correct sefer name. If there is a link to a web page where it is sold, add that. If there is an online reference, add that.