# Prohibition to Wear Freshly Laundered Clothes in the 9 days

Tags: clothing, mourning-aveilus, nine-days

Normally is customary to avoid wearing freshly laundered clothes during the 9 days. Does this apply these days when freshly laundered clothes are no longer exciting and new? Perhaps the parallel today ought to be freshly dry cleaned clothes?

@curiouser [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17765/freshly-laundered-clothes-in-the-nine-days#comment41359_17765) cites Shu"T Siach Nachum by R. Nachum Rabinovitz who apparently holds this. Does anyone know where this responsum can be found, or of other poskim who concur?

Comment: Why are freshly dry cleaned clothes exciting?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm still quivering from my last shirt shirt from the cleaners!

Comment: @DoubleAA - Dry cleaned clothes feel so amazing! I'm always excited when I get something from the dry cleaners. I agree with mevaqesh here.

Comment: @ezra I rarely dry clean anything. Maybe it is really qualitatively better than wet cleaning, and I'm just missing out.

Answer (score 1):

In the book "Pninei-Halach" it is written that also today we have to keep this tradition.

So what is the difference between laundry and lets say taking a shower? Why this we do keep and this we don't? From my understanding is that a Minhag we have to keep also if the reason is gone, unless there is also a reason why not to keep it. In the example i brought, the reason why we were not able to take a shower was because it was a happy occasion in the past. Today it isn't, but that is not enough to let us take a shower we are able to take these days a shower in the 9 days because it is hard not take a shower those days. So true these days when freshly laundered clothes are no longer exciting and new, but it is not difficult to keep the minhag (It is not too hard to wear clothes that are not completely fresh).

Best wishes!

Comment: welcome. please identify the author of this work. a citation would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hey
* The Rabbi is Rabbi Eliezer Melamed (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Melamed)
* The reasoning for why this is allowed and this isn't is from Rabbi's I heard. If you want i can also find for this reasoning citations but that might take time.
 * The citation that laundry also in these days is not allowed is in Hebrew (His whole book is meant for these days): 
http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/3812
In the article go to איסורי כביסה

Comment: @Tomer Please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/66435/edit) that information into your answer.

Comment: For the record, I’m pretty sure the reason many don’t hold of not showering is because it’s no longer considered normal to shower once a week. Things were a little different when you could just do this week’s shower a little early and next week’s shower a little late.

Answer (score 0):

[R. Nachum Rabinovitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum_Rabinovitch) wrote to me that it is permissible to do laundry during the 9 days, and that there is no difference between dry-cleaning and other sorts of laundry.

Comment: He referenced this as the opinion of the Aruch Hashulchan, but after a cursory examination of the Aruch Hashulchan I couldnt find it. If someone else can, please edit it in.

Comment: Does this also apply during Shavua SheChal Bo when the prohibition isn't just a custom but Dina deGemara (or more properly deMatnitin)?

Comment: That is definitely not the accepted minhag among Ashkenazim.

Answer (score 0):

We are compared to a mourner during Shloshim, who may not clean or launder his clothing, nor may he wear freshly laundered clothing. This is clearly stated in Yoreh Deah and commentaries. The idea behind this is not that it is exciting and new to wear freshly cleaned clothing, but we do this to help us feel the mourning of the Bais Hamikdosh (Temple). By not wearing freshly laundered clothing, our simcha is lessened and it states in the Mishna Brura 25 that anyone who properly mourns over Jerusalem will be rewarded by experiencing its rejoicing.