# Using fabric refresher spray during the Nine Days

Tags: nine-days, washing-clothes

The entire duration of the Nine Days, one is forbidden to wear freshly-laundered clothes, as it  is part of the process of mourning for the Churban Beit HaMikdash.

However, are you permitted to use a fabric refresher spray, like [this one](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Febreze-Fabric-Refresher-April-Fresh-16-9-FL-OZ/180547234?action=product_interest&action_type=title&beacon_version=1.0.2&bucket_id=irsbucketdefault&client_guid=b1ecc027-40f0-42ba-8f4b-4d3d4d55feba&config_id=106&customer_id_enc&findingMethod=p13n&guid=b1ecc027-40f0-42ba-8f4b-4d3d4d55feba&item_id=180547234&parent_anchor_item_id=17061840&parent_item_id=17061840&placement_id=irs-106-t1&reporter=recommendations&source=new_site&strategy=PWVUB&visitor_id=ZCgpWp8kNVm8py3a4bOo6c), to fresh-up your clothes and make them smell nicer?

Comment: Just a hunch that someone may have asked this. I have to hunt. Offhand, I know that there is a leniency that one may shower to wash off sweat or if he emits an odor. I would assume that if one cannot find any odorless clothes to wear, he should be able to launder what he must wear immediately. If that's true, then, I can't see why he couldn't use deodorant. There is nothing that says that you must smell bad during the 9 Days just because you can't shower or launder.

Comment: There are many exceptions to your general assumption about cleaning your clothes during the 9 days. For some examples see Mishna Berurah 100:29-30 and Rav Shimon Eider's Summary of the Halachos of the Three Weeks, pg. 10, III D 11.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Source for first sentence? Note https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61483/8775.

Comment: @mevaqesh Did you ever locate the Aruch HaShulchan citation you were looking for? As I was browsing the subject in the Rav Eider pamphlet, he was bringing Aruch HaShulchan quite a bit.