# Using laundered underwear, bed sheets and towels during the nine days

Tags: halacha, clothing, mourning-aveilus, nine-days

If [underwear, bed sheets, or towels](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17943) were laundered during the 9 days, is it permissible to benefit from (wear or use) them during the 9 days?

Comment: Very closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/permissible-laundry-during-the-9-days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question and found this answer online:
The bottom line is: R' Moshe Feinstein rules that while one should not wear freshly laundered underclothing during the nine days, if one doesn't have any  (preworn) underclothes he/she can wear whatever they have. 
Link to above article: http://www.vbm-torah.org/3weeks/mf.htm

I'm not sure if this ruling includes bed sheets, however I found another website which discusses this: 
Here is the link: http://www.beingjewish.com/yomtov/mitzorim/ninedays.html
This website also says that you can wear 'any' laundered clothes (and use fresh linens)if nothing else is available.

IMPORTANT: One should always consult a Rav with any hallachic questions and not rules for himself/herself. Asking through a website is not the same as asking directly to a Rav, which is the proper way.
Hatzlocho! 
May we be zoche the geulah hasheleima when these days will be converted into days of rejoicing and happiness! May it be speedily now.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mr. 6816!  Thank you for your well-sourced and well-linked answer.  We hope to see you around!  You could consider registering your account and finding a more descriptive user name (unless 6816 really fits you).